# How to exclude the first couple of lines of code when restarting a function?

Tags: python, function

I have a python function that is basically a game. The first couple of lines in this game are just printed out rules of the game. When the game ends and the player's final input is to 'repeat' the game, the function restarts.

My question is: how do I exclude the first couple of lines of code when restarting a function?

Comment: Print it only if a `repeating` boolean is `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a keyword argument with a default value and when the player 'repeats' the game, set this to a value you can use to skip the rules;

```
    def run_game(skip_rules=False):
        if !skip_rules:
            print("Here's how to play the game...")

        # rest of your function code
```

So when you start the game the 1st time, just call `run_game()` - when the player repeats the game pass in the keyword argument `run_game(skip_rules=True)`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is by creating a while loop inside the function instead of restarting it. Wrap the code you want to repeat in a `while True` loop, and put the code you only want to show once before it. Then, if the user wants to restart, you can `continue` and if the user wants to end the game, you can `break`. This will also mean you only have to call your main function once, and it will automatically repeat when necessary and end when necessary. That is also a better python custom, as you should only usually call your main function once, inside a code block that looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```